# Removed lock after "could not get lock", now I get "post installation script was interrupted"

Tags: apt, dpkg, lock

I'm unable to remove lock from dpkg, and it seems `docker-ce` installation was stopped midway:

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
$ sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
$ sudo apt install aptitude
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
$ sudo rm -R /var/lib/dpkg/lock
$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': No such file or directory
$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': No such file or directory
$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/lock': No such file or directory
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up docker-ce (17.06.2~ce-0~ubuntu) ...
^Cdpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was interrupted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
```

I have deleted `lock` files, but I get the same message. Using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You are still installing `docker-ce`. Why did you force interupt the post-installation script of `docker-ce`?

Comment: I had to, it never finishes.

Comment: are you running another package manager in another terminal or software center ?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

You already removed the package manager log but the package configuration was still interrupted. You need to reinstall the docker package from scratch with `dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb`.

This won't resolve the original issue of the Docker installation. Please [open a new question](/questions/ask) for that and include the output of the installation command. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't help, dpkg is still locked 

`arton@arton-Latitude-E6230:~$ sudo dpkg -i /home/arton/Downloads/amd64/docker.io_1.12.6-0ubuntu1~16.04.1A~4.2.0.201703241951_amd64.deb`
`[sudo] password for arton: dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process`